# force to write uppercase in searchview in android

Tags: android, android-appcompat, searchview

I need to force user to write in uppercase letters in searchview v7 Do you know a way to do that? similar to that used in editText:

```
filter_text.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Comment: in EditText you can also do this via xml attribute ... now SearchView from support pass a lots attributes related with edittext to its own edittext ... did you tried?

Comment: You should put android:inputType="textCapCharacters" in the xml

Comment: I'm adding the searchview programmatically btw how can i add textCapCharacters?

Comment: then google for how get its inner edittext... such questions were already asked

Comment: @Selvin give the link of those solutions plz

Comment: yeah, sure: [here](https://google.com) ... strange, i thought that you know this link ... **remeber, SO is not human search engine**

Comment: @Selvin Thx you saved my life  -_-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In code you can do so by adding the following.

`searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);`

All of the other things you can add can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: This one is working fine but its not working in API level 28 the search view is still searching with small characters

Comment: This is what works for API level 28+: searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**:

Actually a better way is to do

`searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);`

**Alternatively**, you can also set the `android:inputType` to `textCapWords` inside `searchable.xml` that you will create if you followed the official `SearchView` setup guide.

https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force user to write in uppercase letters on your `EditText`, you just need to add `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` and your keyboard on device will set into uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

To write the fisrt capital letter only you can use this code:

```
search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Answer (score 0):

**API level 28+:**

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS)
```

**Kotlin**

```
inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS
```